# in FlUrl I try to use EnableCookies() and it throw a null reference exception

Tags: c#, cookies, async-await, flurl

when I try to execute:

```
            using (var fc = new FlurlClient().EnableCookies())
            {
                var resp = "http://somesite.com".GetAsync();
                // var getResp = await "http://api.foo.com".GetAsync();

                var resultado = await resp;

                var x = resultado;
            }
```

I get a null reference exception on EnableCookies()

stack:

```
   en Flurl.Url.op_Implicit(Url url) en C:\Aldenteware\Flurl\code\Flurl\Url.cs:línea 315
   en Flurl.Http.CookieExtensions.GetCookieContainer(FlurlClient client) en C:\Aldenteware\Flurl\code\Flurl.Http.Shared\CookieExtensions.cs:línea 145
   en Flurl.Http.CookieExtensions.EnableCookies(FlurlClient client) en C:\Aldenteware\Flurl\code\Flurl.Http.Shared\CookieExtensions.cs:línea 23
   en AfipProcesa.Form1.<flurlAsync>d__0.MoveNext() en c:\Users\fabian.LH\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AfipProcesa\AfipProcesa\Form1.cs:línea 86
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en AfipProcesa.Form1.<button1_Click>d__7.MoveNext() en c:\Users\fabian.LH\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AfipProcesa\AfipProcesa\Form1.cs:línea 119
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__4(Object state)
```

I have to do something more or in another way?

I put it on a flurl error handler but it not catch it (as it is a null ex)

I starting to use await/async and flurl at same time... sorry if I'm making a basic mistake.

I using as a example the code on http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/client-lifetime/

```
using (var fc = new FlurlClient().EnableCookies())
{
    await url
        .AppendPathSegment("login")
        .WithClient(fc)
        .PostUrlEncodedAsync(new { user = "user", pass = "pass" });

    var page = await url
        .AppendPathSegment("home")
        .WithClient(fc)
        .GetStringAsync();

    // Need to inspect the cookies? FlurlClient exposes them as a dictionary.
    var sessionId = fc.Cookies["session_id"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've spotted a bug related to recent changes to address [this issue](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/66). The work-around is to seed FlurlClient with the base URL:

`using (var fc = new FlurlClient(url).EnableCookies())`

I'll log this issue and address it soon, it clearly doesn't work as documented.

Comment: thank you so much, it now works, sorry for not be of much help downloading source and checking myself what is happening, I tried but I have vs2013, I still learning all about httpclient and my idea is to use flurl to replace watin+IE to automate checking bank movements automatically each day  =)

Comment: No problem. The 1.0 release of Flurl.Http is very close so I'm really glad you spotted this blatant bug. I updated the docs to reflect the work-around, at least until I fix the bug.